# free-jqGrid - The numeric value is displayed instead of the text for select cell

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

I am using free jqgrid version 4.13.2 and i have a grid with 2 select columns and a custom column with multiple checkboxes per cell.

One of the select columns has the values hardcoded and it works perfectly. The other one creates the select string dynamicly based on another grids rows and as far as i can see, it has nothing different from the working select.

When i am in edit, they are displayed correctly but after the row gets saved the dynamicly filled select displays the numeric value and so does the checkbox column.

My question is, is there something wrong with the generated select string? What can i do to get them working?

[image]
[image]

```
 function getSpecificCell(grid, col){
        var id = grid.find('tr[aria-selected="true"]').attr('id');
        return grid.jqGrid('getRowData',id)[col];
    }
 function getAdresseSelectValues(){
     var adrese = $("#adreseGrid").getGridParam('data'),
         adreseDeReturnat="";
     for(var i=0;i<adrese.length;i++){
         adreseDeReturnat += adrese[i].adresseId + ":Str. " +  adrese[i].streetId +" Nr. " + adrese[i].streetNumber;
         if(adrese[i].building){
             adreseDeReturnat += "Bl. " + adrese[i].building;
         }
         if(adrese[i].floor){
             adreseDeReturnat += " Etaj "+ adrese[i].floor;
         }
         if(adrese[i].apartament){
             adreseDeReturnat += " Ap. " + adrese[i].apartament;
         }
         if(adrese[i].interPhone){
             adreseDeReturnat += " Interfon: " + adrese[i].interPhone;
         }
         adreseDeReturnat += ";";

     }
     adreseDeReturnat = adreseDeReturnat.substring(0,adreseDeReturnat.length-1);
     return adreseDeReturnat;
 }

var custOrdGrid = $("#customersOrdersGrid"),
    custOrdPager = "#customersOrdersPager",
    restURL = "/LicentaREST/rest/",
    validationCount={},
    getOrderDDLs = {};
getOrderDDLs = ajaxCall(restURL+"ddl/getOrderDDL");
var pizzaValues = getOrderDDLs.pizzaValues,
    pasteValues = getOrderDDLs.hamburgerValues,
    hamburgerValues = getOrderDDLs.pasteValues,
    drinksValues = getOrderDDLs.drinksValues,
    desertValues = getOrderDDLs.desertValues;
    custOrdGrid.jqGrid({
        datatype: "local",
        mtype: "POST",
        url: restURL + "orders/getCustomerOrders",
        editurl: restURL +"orders/createUpdateOrder",
        colModel: [
             { name: "orderId", index:"orderId",label:"",key:true,hidden:true},
             { name: "custId", index:"custId",label:"",hidden:true},
             { name: 'createdBy', index: 'createdBy', label:'Creat de', width: 90,editable: false,hidden:true },
             { name: 'orderedBy', index: 'orderedBy',search:false, label:'Client', width: 50, editable: false},
             { name: 'phoneNumber', index: 'phoneNumber',label:'Telefon',editable: false,width: 50},
             { name: 'pizza', index: 'pizza',editable: true,search:false,edittype:"custom",
                 editrules: {custom: true, custom_func: function(value,colname){
                    if(value=="" || value==null){
                        validationCount[colname] = false;
                    }
                    else{
                        validationCount[colname] = true;
                    }
                     return [true, ""];
                }},
                 editoptions:{custom_element:multiCheckElem, custom_value:multiCheckVal,list:pizzaValues,dataEvents:[
                                {type: 'change', data:{ i: 7 }, fn: function(e) { onChangeFunc(e,custOrdGrid,getOrderDDLs);}}]}, label:'Pizza', width: 86 },
             { name: 'paste', index: 'paste',editable: true,search:false,edittype:"custom",
                                    editrules: {custom: true, custom_func: function(value,colname){
                                        if(value=="" || value==null){
                                            validationCount[colname] = false;
                                        }
                                        else{
                                            validationCount[colname] = true;
                                        }
                                         return [true, ""];
                                    }},
                                    editoptions:{custom_element:multiCheckElem, custom_value:multiCheckVal,list:pasteValues,dataEvents:[
                                {type: 'change', data:{ i: 7 }, fn: function(e) { onChangeFunc(e,custOrdGrid,getOrderDDLs);}}]}, label:'Paste', width: 80 },
             { name: 'hamburger', index: 'hamburger',editable: true,search:false,edittype:"custom",
                                    editrules: {custom: true, custom_func: function(value,colname){
                                        if(value=="" || value==null){
                                            validationCount[colname] = false;
                                        }
                                        else{
                                            validationCount[colname] = true;
                                        }
                                         return [true, ""];
                                    }},
                                    editoptions:{custom_element:multiCheckElem, custom_value:multiCheckVal,list:hamburgerValues,dataEvents:[
                                {type: 'change', data:{ i: 7 }, fn: function(e) { onChangeFunc(e,custOrdGrid,getOrderDDLs);}}]}, label:'Hamburger', width: 80 },
             { name: 'drinks', index: 'drinks',search:false,editable: true,edittype:"custom",
                                    editrules: {custom: true, custom_func: function(value,colname){
                                        if(value=="" || value==null){
                                            validationCount[colname] = false;
                                        }
                                        else{
                                            validationCount[colname] = true;
                                        }
                                         return [true, ""];
                                    }},
                                    editoptions:{custom_element:multiCheckElem, custom_value:multiCheckVal,list:drinksValues,dataEvents:[
                                {type: 'change', data:{ i: 7 }, fn: function(e) { onChangeFunc(e,custOrdGrid,getOrderDDLs);}}]}, label:'Bauturi', width: 80 },
             { name: 'desert', index: 'desert',search:false,editable: true,edittype:"custom",
                                    editrules: {custom: true, custom_func: function(value,colname){
                                        if(value=="" || value==null){
                                            validationCount[colname] = false;
                                        }
                                        else{
                                            validationCount[colname] = true;
                                        }
                                        if(validationCount.Pizza === false && validationCount.Paste === false && validationCount.Hamburger === false && validationCount.Bauturi === false && validationCount.Desert === false ){
                                            return [false,'Cel putin un produs trebuie selectat'];
                                        }
                                         return [true, ""];
                                    }},
                                    editoptions:{custom_element:multiCheckElem, custom_value:multiCheckVal,list:desertValues,dataEvents:[
                                {type: 'change', data:{ i: 7 }, fn: function(e) { onChangeFunc(e,custOrdGrid,getOrderDDLs);}}]}, label:'Desert', width: 80 },
             { name: 'notes', index: 'notes',label:'Nota',edittype:'textarea', editoptions: { rows: "12", cols: "20"}, width: 80,editable: true},
             { name: 'total', index: 'total',label:'Total', width: 40,editable: false,align:'center' },
             { name: 'orderedAt', index:'orderedAt', label:'Data', width: 80,formatter: 'date', formatoptions: {newformat:"d/m/Y"},search:false},
             { name: 'adresa', index:'adresa',label:'Adresa',formatter:'select',stype:'select',searchoptions: {sopt: ['eq','ne'],value: getAdresseSelectValues()},editable:true,edittype:'select',editoptions:{value: getAdresseSelectValues}},
             { name: 'orderStatus', index: 'orderStatus', label:'Status',stype:'select',edittype:'select', editoptions:{value:"1:Comanda Primita;2:Comanda in livrare;3:Comanda anulata de client;4:Comanda refuzata de client;5:Comanda Finalizata"},formatter:'select', width: 90,editable: true}
        ],
        pager: custOrdPager,
        rowNum: 10,
        beforeProcessing: function(data){
            if(data && data.length>0){
                var test = getAdresseSelectValues();
                console.log(test);
                for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){

                    data[i].orderedAt = new Date(data[i].orderedAt);
                    data[i].total += " lei";
                }
            }
            console.log(getAdresseSelectValues());
        },
        ajaxGridOptions: {contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'},
        serializeGridData: function (postData) {
              postData = parseInt($("#customersGrid").find('tr[aria-selected="true"]').attr('id'));
              return JSON.stringify(postData);
          },
        rowList: [10, 50, 100, 250,500],
        sortname: 'id',
        loadonce: true,
        rownumbers: true,
        forceClientSorting: true,
        inlineEditing: {
            ajaxSaveOptions: { contentType: "application/json" },
            serializeSaveData: function (postData) {
                if(postData.oper == "add"){
                    postData.createdBy = $("#userIdSession").val();
                    postData.custId = $("#customersGrid").find("tr[aria-selected='true']").attr("id");
                    postData.createdAt = new Date();
                }
                if(postData.oper == "edit"){
                    var data =custOrdGrid.getRowData(postData.orderId);
                    postData.createdBy = data.createdBy;
                    postData.custId = data.custId;
                }
                postData.adresa=parseInt(postData.adresa.replace('"',""),10);
                postData.total = parseInt(custOrdGrid.jqGrid("getCell",postData.orderId,"total"),10);
                return JSON.stringify(postData);
            }
        },
        height: 220,
        iconSet: "fontAwesome",
        sortorder: 'desc',
        viewrecords: true,
        caption: 'Customer Orders',
        autowidth: true

 });
```

Comment: It seems you have a typing bug: `editoptions:{value: getAdresseSelectValues}` should be fixed to `editoptions:{value: getAdresseSelectValues()}` like `searchoptions: {sopt: ['eq','ne'],value: getAdresseSelectValues()}`, which you already use. Additionally consider to use `height: "auto"` instead of `height: 220`. You can use `maxHeight: 220` **additionally** if you want to restrict the max height of the grid.

Comment: Good evening Oleg, thank you for your reply. It seems that if i change editoptions from getAdresseSelectValues to getAdresseSelectValues(), the dropdownlist doesnt load at all, not even in edit mode for some reason. I will implement the height suggestion right now, thank you.

Comment: You are welcome! It's difficult to understand which value you want to assign to `editoptions.value`. An example of `getAdresseSelectValues()` could be helpful. I'd recommend you to remove all `index` properties from `colModel` and to use more intensive column templates (see [the old answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6047856/315935) for more details). It will allows to reduce the size of your code and to remove code dupplicates.

Comment: You can remove `searchoptions.value` in many cases if you use `editoptions.value`. See [here](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/master/README4.13.1.md#main-new-features-and-improvements-implemented-in-the-version-4131). The usage of 4.13.3 would be better as 4.13.2 too because it contains [some fixes](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/master/README.md#below-one-can-see-the-full-list-of-changes-in-the-version-4133-compared-with-4132)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, i will make the changes now. Here is a example of what getAdresseSelectValues() returns and what comes from DB for the "adresa" column. `26:Str. sadasdsd Nr. 34Bl. asdas Etaj asda Ap. asda;27:Str. asdasdada Nr. 123Bl. 123 Etaj 123 Ap. 123` and from db: 26

Comment: You use `$("#adreseGrid").getGridParam('data')` inside of `getAdresseSelectValues()`. It seems to me the main problem, which you have. You should set `editoptions.value` with respect of `setColProp` **inside of `beforeProcessing`** to fix your main problem. See [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17410568/315935) or better [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19427444/315935)

Comment: Oleg, thank you so much! That fixed my problem. For the multiple checkboxes columns i will make a custom formatter that should fix the problem there also. Feel free to post a answer so i can accept it. Thanks alot!

Comment: A quick question, if i were to use this for multiple checkboxes in a single column, would i be able to display the selected values after save? Instead of "3 selected" how it appears in the demo you posted there. [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10847644/is-there-anyway-to-include-a-multiselect-combobox-in-a-jqgrid/10851429#10851429)

Comment: You are welcome! I'll post my answer later. About "3 selected" message: `multiselect` supports the option, which allows to specify after how many selected items it displays ""3 selected"". You should increase the value of `selectedList: 2` option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use `datatype: "local"`, but `mtype: "POST"`, `url: restURL + "orders/getCustomerOrders"` and `beforeProcessing` options/callbacks, which shows that you do load the data from the server. The column `adresa` have the following properties

```
{
    name: 'adresa', index:'adresa',label:'Adresa',
    formatter:'select',
    stype:'select',searchoptions: {sopt: ['eq','ne'],value: getAdresseSelectValues()},
    editable:true,edittype:'select',editoptions:{value: getAdresseSelectValues()}
}
```

with `formatter:'select'`. It means that the data for `adresa` column return from the server are numbers like 26 and 27 on your first picture and you want to display there as texts `Str. sadasdsd Nr. 34Bl. asdas Etaj asda Ap. asda` and `Str. asdasdada Nr. 123Bl. 123 Etaj 123 Ap. 123` because of usage `editoptions.value` defined as

```
"26:Str. sadasdsd Nr. 34Bl. asdas Etaj asda Ap. asda;27:Str. asdasdada Nr. 123Bl. 123 Etaj 123 Ap. 123"
```

The problem only is: you want to load the data **from the server too**. The data will be filled in the grid using `formatter:'select'`. Thus the value `editoptions.value` of the column `adresa` have to be set/modified **before** the formatter start working.

I suggest you to use `beforeProcessing` callback, where you process the server response and set/modify `editoptions.value` of the column `adresa`. You can use `setColProp`, for example, for setting `editoptions.value`. See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17410568/315935) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19427444/315935) for more implementation details.

I'd recommend you to use column template additionally (see [the old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6047856/315935)) to reduce code duplicates in your code. It will simplify later modification/maintain of your code.

Some additional advices: you use *hidden* column `name: "orderId"` with `key:true` property. The value will be saved in `<td>` of the column *and* as the value of `id` attribute of the row (`<tr>`). I suggest you to remove the column and to use `jsonReader: { id: "orderId" }` instead (or `localReader: {id: "orderId"}` if you load the data not from the server). It will inform jqGrid to assign rowids based on the value of `orderId` property of input data. Additionally jqGrid will use `orderId` as the name of rowid during editing (set to `editurl`) instead of default name `id`.

You can consider to remove other hidden columns too (`custId` and `createdBy`). You need just add the option `additionalProperties: ["orderId", "custId", "createdBy"]` to inform jqGrid to read the *properties* from input data. The properties will be seen in custom formatter, `rowattr`, `cellattr` and be saved in the local `data` (accessible by `getLocalRow` method). In other words, the data will be save in JavaScript objects, but not in the DOM. It makes HTML/DOM cleaner and improve the performance of the page.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I managed to get it working and ill apply the modifications you suggested also. I am curious, is there a documentation page for free-jqGrid similar to the one from trirand website aimed at the original jqGrid? The one from gifthub only shows the modifications made in each version, if i am not mistaken, right?

Comment: @IvanSt: You are welcome! I started writing the documentation [here](http://free-jqgrid.github.io/getting-started/index.html), but it contains not so many information. It's difficult to spend many time to the product which I provide to free. :-) I plan to extend the information provided on http://free-jqgrid.github.io/

Comment: Oh, i totaly understand. Thanks alot for the link.